# Transforming Json File onto SQl Server

Tags: python, json, sql-server

After creating a json file, I want to translate it to an database sql file. I tried using create_engine class to help me with that. After executing the code it gave me a Json decode error even though I checked the file it's in a correct json form.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import json
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"}
output='['
print("[",end='')
for page in range(1,3): 
    req = requests.get('https://www.zomato.com/beirut/deek-duke-ashrafieh/reviews?page=' + str(page) + '&sort=dd&filter=reviews-dd',headers=headers)
    soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for tag in soup.find_all('script')[1]:
        if page==2:
            print(tag[1448:-2])
            output+=tag[1448:-2]
        else:  print(tag[1448:-2],end=",") 
        output+=tag[1448:-2]
        


    sleep(randint(2,10))
print("]")
output+=']'
with open('json_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(output)

with open('json_data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///my_data.db")
df.to_sql("table_name",conn=engine)
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Don't create json file manually because you may create wrong format - it may looks OK on screen but it may have small mistakes. Better create normal `list` and use `output = json.dumps(your_list)`. But if you will have already this list then you can use it directly with `DataFrame` without writing to file and reading it again. Frankly, your code suggest that you create single list so you could use `.csv` without `[ ]`

Comment: your code display text which starts with `[ews"` and there is first mistake - `ews` has closing `"` but it doesn't have opening `"` - it needs `["ews"`. But it seems you crop too much - it should be `"reviews"`

Comment: I see two other problems. First: you run one `output += ...` inside `if` but second `output += ...` is outside `else` - so it will add element two times. Second: you forgot to add `,` after every `output += ...` - you only display it with `print()`. So you display different value on screen and you save different data in file.

Comment: Just use a proper serializer, then you won't have mistakes in your JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few mistakes.

Main problem is that you crop `tag` in wrong places so you have `ews": [{"author": ...}` but it should be `"reviews": [{"author": ...}]` or `{"author": ...}` and then it makes sense to put it in `[ ]`

Second: you have wrong indentations and second `output +=...` is outside `else` so it may add the same elements two times

Third: you print with `end=','` but you forgot to add `,` in output - so elements are not separated.

---

You write in file and read it from file but you could use directly `output` with `json.loads()`.

It would be simpler to append elements to normal list and later convert all to `output` using `join()`

```
output = "[" + ",".join(all_items) + "]"
```

---

This code works for me - but it may need to edit data to extract details to separated columns

```py
import json
from time import sleep
from random import randint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"
}

all_items = []

for page in range(1,3 ): 
    print(f'--- page: {page} ---')

    url = f'https://www.zomato.com/beirut/deek-duke-ashrafieh/reviews?page={page}&sort=dd&filter=reviews-dd'
    response = requests.get(url ,headers=headers)
    soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    for tag in soup.find_all('script')[1]:
        item = tag[1454:-2]
        all_items.append(item)
        print(item)
        print('--------')

    sleep(randint(2,10))

# --- after loop ---

output = '[' + ',\n'.join(all_items) + ']'

data = json.loads(output)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
print(df.columns)
```

Result:

```
           author  ...                                       reviewRating
0   Youssef Semaan  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 1, 'bestRat...
1   Doublethatfood  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRat...
2    Zeina El Zein  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 4, 'bestRat...
3      Leilajoheir  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 4, 'bestRat...
4     Eliane Lteif  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 4, 'bestRat...
5     Rabih Hjeily  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 5, 'bestRat...
6      Rami Bazzal  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 1, 'bestRat...
7    Hisham Buteen  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 1, 'bestRat...
8  Engred Bou Aoun  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 1, 'bestRat...
9       Ahmad Harb  ...  {'@type': 'Rating', 'ratingValue': 4, 'bestRat...

[10 rows x 4 columns]

Index(['author', 'url', 'description', 'reviewRating'], type='object')
```

---

**EDIT::**

After adding

```py
df = df.join(df['reviewRating'].apply(pd.Series))
```

I get details from `reviewRating` in separated columns

```
            author                          url  ... bestRating worstRating
0   Youssef Semaan  https://www.zoma.to/qvQeaRp  ...          5           0
1   Doublethatfood  https://www.zoma.to/kaMAPOn  ...          5           0
2    Zeina El Zein  https://www.zoma.to/BNMYBar  ...          5           0
3      Leilajoheir  https://www.zoma.to/ddGNypx  ...          5           0
4     Eliane Lteif  https://www.zoma.to/oQdmkyE  ...          5           0
5     Rabih Hjeily  https://www.zoma.to/eaOrzBn  ...          5           0
6      Rami Bazzal  https://www.zoma.to/YKGYppO  ...          5           0
7    Hisham Buteen  https://www.zoma.to/ZPodbDv  ...          5           0
8  Engred Bou Aoun  https://www.zoma.to/ddqNLqb  ...          5           0
9       Ahmad Harb  https://www.zoma.to/QbAvDZQ  ...          5           0

[10 rows x 8 columns]

Index(['author', 'url', 'description', 'reviewRating', '@type', 'ratingValue', 'bestRating', 'worstRating'], dtype='object')
```

---

**EDIT:**

To add table to database you have to use `con=` instead of `conn=`.

For `SQLite` you have to drop column `reviewRating` because it has dictionary and `SQLite` has problem with this type of data.

```
df = df.drop(columns='reviewRating')
```

If you want to replace existing table then you need also `if_exists='replace'`

If you want to add new data to existing table then you need also `if_exists='append'`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.join(df['reviewRating'].apply(pd.Series))
df = df.drop(columns='reviewRating')

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///my_data.db")

df.to_sql("table_name", con=engine, if_exists='replace') 
#df.to_sql("table_name", con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

---

For `SQL server management` you need different value in `create_engine()` - see SQLAlchemy: [Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it looks like the website changes its html code that's why the slicer seemed the wrong and thanks for realizing my mistake for the output in the if statement. One more thing, how do i make it show in my sql server management after this conversion?

Comment: usually `SQL Server` means `Microsoft SQL Server` but you use `SQLite`. I don't have `Microsoft SQL Server` and I can say only for `SQLite`. You have to use `con=` instead of `conn=`, And you have to drop column `reviewRating` because it has dictionary and `SQLite` has problem with it - `df = df.drop(columns='reviewRating')`. I will add this to answer.

Comment: I also use SQL server(SQL server management) It's actually my preferred one now. So i assume i use conn=

Comment: you should always use `con=` but you should use different value in `create_engine()` for `SQL server management` - see SQLAlchemy: [Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server)